# Passing variable values between class methods

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to pass a value between methods in a Ruby class.

I haven't found much on my own and figured I would ask the experts. Could it be done passed as a arg/parameter to another method as well?

```
class PassingValues

  def initialize
    @foo = 1
  end

  def one
    @foo += 1
  end

  def two
    @foo += 1
  end

  def three
    p @foo
  end

end

bar = PassingValues.new
```

If I wanted this to print out foo value of 3:

```
bar.three
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `bar.three` to print a 3 you will need to call before the one and two methods to ensure the variable is updated to the three so:

```
class PassingValues

  def initialize
    @foo = 1
  end

  def one
    @foo += 1
  end

  def two
    one
    @foo += 1
  end

  def three
    two
    p @foo
  end

end
```

Anyway this doesn't make sense as long as the methods will be eventually modifying the variable, so each time you call one of them the number will increase the amount expected.

Answer (score 0):

Those are instance methods, not class methods. And `@foo` is already shared among them.

```
bar = PassingValues.new
bar.one
bar.two
bar.three
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `@foo` is an instance variable and it can be referenced (it is not passed here) in any method of the class.

When you call you create `bar` as an instance of the class using: `PassingValues.new`
it is initialized, and sets `@foo` to 1.

When you then call the method `three` using `bar.three`, you simply print out `@foo`, which is still equal to 1.

You can change your `three` method to increment `@foo` by 2, so it is now equal to 3, then print:

```
 def three  
    @foo += 2  
    p @foo  
 end
```